# wxPython create a huge clickable list with sub-lists during run time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, user-interface, wxpython

I’m quite new to Python so I’m having a bit of trouble here.

I’m trying to create like a ‘directory tree’ if you know what I’m taking about. 
So like below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f89M3.jpg

I want all the directories (Program Files, Windows, Adobe etc..) to be clickable to fold and unfold and to open the directories.

Now my question though, is how can I generate the full directories list during run time with each element clickable, with wxPython, while not freezing the application as well, as it goes through the whole C and D drives.

I tried putting a lot of text into StaticText but the application froze and I had to force close it, the same occurs if I add a delay inside the loop (that reads my text file)

P.S. I already know how to get the directories text and I can probably figure out how to break those paths into levels.

So I mainly need the wxPython part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.GenericDirCtrl.html ?

Comment: Thanks! I’ll look into it, I’m currently trying to use TreeCtrl but if any problems arise performance wise or any, I’ll look into that.  Edit: it actually says that it uses TreeCtrl itself, so I’m on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the answer is to use `wx.TreeCtrl`, then I was able to create a loop with inner loops to create the directory tree, so far I only tried with 2 levels which works flawlessly, hopefully it will work well with many more.